# Adafruit Motor Shield and Bridge Library for Yun Shield

Tags: arduino-yun, adafruit, stepper

I am using the Leonardo board with the Adafruit Motor Shield v2, 2 steppers and the Yun Shield. The yun shield and steppers all run harmoniously, however, as soon as I do Bridge.begin() and anything that accesses the Yun shield Bridge library to access the console, the steppers stop running. Is this to be expected and are there any solutions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looking at Bridge.begin() description [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/YunBridgeBegin)
 you can see this is blocking function.

> begin() is a blocking function. Once you call Bridge.begin(), nothing else will happen in your sketch until it has completed. This process takes approximately three seconds.